# I need to change the php code in the file so instead of the current json output

Tags: php, arrays, json

So i am using this PHP code to create the json output, and I am having an issue where it’s creating an array of array with the info. I would like to get rid of one array  and just display the list of API’s thats been used and number that has been used.

in order to do so, I need to change the php code in the file so instead of the current json output which is the one below

```
{
    "api_key": "steven",
    "expiration_date": "2026-02-26 12:33:20",
    "total_usage": "0\n",
    "usage": {
        "zone_1": {
            "total_zone": "0\n",
            "apis": [{
                "item_search": "0\n"
            }, {
                "item_recommended": "0\n"
            }]
        },
        "zone_2": {
            "total_zone": "0\n",
            "apis": [{
                "item_review": "0\n"
            }]
        },
        "zone_3": {
            "total_zone": "0\n",
            "apis": null
        }
    }
}
```

I would return this json string below.

```
{
    "api_key": "steven",
    "expiration_date": "2026-02-26 12:33:20",
    "total_usage": "0\n",
    "usage": {
        "zone_1": {
            "total_zone": "0\n",
            "apis": {
                "item_search": "0\n",
                "item_recommended": "0\n"
            }
        },
        "zone_2": {
            "total_zone": "0\n",
            "apis": {
                "item_review": "0\n"
            }
        },
        "zone_3": {
            "total_zone": "0\n",
            "apis": null
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the PHP code I am using to create the json string.

```
$key = isset($_GET['key'])?$_GET['key']:'';

$keys = array_diff(scandir('./keys'), array('..', '.'));
if (in_array($_GET['key'], $keys)){
  include './keys/'.$_GET['key'].'/key_info.php';
}


$zone_1_apis = array_diff(scandir('keys/'.$_GET['key'].'/zone_1', 1), array('..', '.') );
foreach($zone_1_apis as $api_name ) {
 $zone_1[] = array(
     substr($api_name, 0,-5) => file_get_contents('keys/'.$_GET['key'].'/zone_1/'.$api_name),
   );
}
$zone_2_apis = array_diff(scandir('keys/'.$_GET['key'].'/zone_2', 1), array('..', '.') );
foreach($zone_2_apis as $api_name ) {
 $zone_2[] = array(
     substr($api_name, 0,-5) => file_get_contents('keys/'.$_GET['key'].'/zone_2/'.$api_name),
   );
}
$zone_3_apis = array_diff(scandir('keys/'.$_GET['key'].'/zone_3', 1), array('..', '.') );
foreach($zone_3_apis as $api_name ) {
 $zone_3[] = array(
     substr($api_name, 0,-5) => file_get_contents('keys/'.$_GET['key'].'/zone_3/'.$api_name),
   );
}

$summary = ['api_key' => $key,
       'expiration_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $key_values['expiration']),
           'total_usage' => file_get_contents("keys/".$key."/total_usage.json"),
                 'usage' => [
                            'zone_1' => [
                                         'total_zone' => file_get_contents("keys/".$key."/total_zone_1.json"),
                                         'apis' => $zone_1,
                                        ],
                            'zone_2' => [
                                        'total_zone' => file_get_contents("keys/".$key."/total_zone_2.json"),
                                        'apis' => $zone_2,
                                        ],
                            'zone_3' => [
                                        'total_zone' => file_get_contents("keys/".$key."/total_zone_3.json"),
                                        'apis' => $zone_3,
                                        ],
                            ],

              ];
print_r(json_encode($summary));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks as though the difference is you have...

```
"apis":[{"item_search":"0\n"},{"item_recommended":"0\n"}]
```

and want

```
"apis":{"item_search":"0\n","item_recommended":"0\n"}
```

If this is the case, you need to change the way you build the data from just adding new objects each time to setting the key values directly in the array...

```
$zone_1 = [];
foreach($zone_1_apis as $api_name ) {
     $zone_1[substr($api_name, 0,-5)] = file_get_contents('keys/'.$_GET['key'].'/zone_1/'.$api_name);
}
```

You also need to do the same for `$zone_2` as well.

It may also be good to use `trim()` round some of the values as they also seem to contain `\n` characters, so perhaps...

```
trim(file_get_contents('keys/'.$_GET['key'].'/zone_1/'.$api_name))
```